# Assertion throwing in CarouselSlider during performLayout()

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using [Carousel Slider package](https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider) to display a carousel in my project. It works perfectly but eventually I got the following exception:

```
════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
'package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_fixed_extent_list.dart': Failed assertion: line 269 pos 12: 'firstIndex == 0 || childScrollOffset(firstChild!)! - scrollOffset <= precisionErrorTolerance': is not true.
```

Here is the code of my CarouselSlider:

```
CarouselSlider(
                  items: bannersClone
                      .map(
                        (e) => Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16),
                          child: GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () async {
                             // Some on tap execution here
                            }
                            child: CachedImageCommonWidget(
                              imageUrl: '$kServerBaseUrl/${e.image}',
                              builder: (context, imageProvider) => Container(
                                width: 1000,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  image: DecorationImage(
                                    image: imageProvider,
                                    fit: BoxFit.contain,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                      .toList(),
                  carouselController: controllerBanners,
                  options: CarouselOptions(
                    viewportFraction: 0.78,
                    autoPlay: true,
                    padEnds: false,
                    aspectRatio: 3,
                    autoPlayInterval: const Duration(seconds: 6),
                    onPageChanged: (index, reason) {
                      setState(() {
                        currentIndexBanners = index;
                      });
                    },
                  ),
            ),
```

PS. When the exception triggers, if I "continue", the Carousel keeps working normally